# Can't put circular imageview in adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a listview with a custom adapter in which there is a imageview. This imageview would be circular and to to that i use this class:

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }
    Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


            return output;
}

}
```

if i write in my layout xml

```
 <com.myapp.utility.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

It works! and i get that image rounded. But the imageview are more than one and to add at adapter i do in this way:

```
   @Override 
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
            }

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setBackgroundResource(myImageList[i]);  


            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(names[i]);
            TextView textSpec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_spec);
            textSpec.setText(ruolo[i]);

            return view;
        }
```

In here: `image.setBackgroundResource(myImageList[i]);`  i set my images but i can't show the images circular as when i set the image static. I tried also to write:

```
CircularImageView image = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

But still not change..what's wrong?

Comment: Can you try `setImageResource()` instead of `SetBackgroundResource`? As far as i know, they are different resources.

Comment: Oh my.. it works! -.-".. my fault! So sorry and thank you so much!